# Ошибка "Invalid syntax" при запуске программы

Tags: python

Только начал осваивать Питон (по книге "Изучаем программирование на Питон", автор Пол Берри - проблемы с примерами) и не могу понять, почему не работает 
пример. Вот сам код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from vsearch import search4letters

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello() -> str:
    return 'Hello world from Flask!'


@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> str:
    return str(search4letters('life, the universe, and everything', 'eiru,!')


@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_teamplate('entry.html',
                        the_title='Welcome to search4 letters on the web!')

app.run(debug=True)
```

При запуске <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> вылетает на 18 строке на объявлении метода - сообщение - "Invalid syntax". Это может быть связано с тем что, я с работы это делаю? Т.е. права там какие или еще что? Спасибо.

Comment: Эта ошибка вероятнее всего сигнализирует о том, что набрали код с опечаткой. Перепроверьте ещё раз, повнимательнее эту строчку и соседние. Хотя вот на глаз (я не питонист) не вижу ничего подозрительного. Хотя... может быть кавычки на слове html не нужны, типа это выходной тип метода?

Comment: Подсказка: у вас незакрытая скобка

Comment: Кстати, да. У вас число открывающих скобок не совпало с числом закрывающих. Посмотрите чуть выше строки 18.

Comment: Спасибо, количество скобок я не заметил - сделал, чтобы правильно было и ошибка ушла но появилась другая -

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\webapp\vsearch4web.py", line 22, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)

Comment: File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 217, in echo
    file = _default_text_stdout()
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 621, in func
    rv = wrapper_func()
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 385, in get_text_stdout

Comment: File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 217, in echo
    file = _default_text_stdout()
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 621, in func
    rv = wrapper_func()
  File "C:\Users\kalinushkin.aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 385, in get_text_stdout

Comment: * Может кто с таким встречался?

Comment: @aka86, пощадите чужие глаза! Выложите этот стек трассы в вопрос, добавив форматирование :)